# Group by similar number SQL (oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to find the number of sales that have a similar purchase value from the following table:

```
sale_number | value 
------------+-------
 1          |    10
 2          |    11
 3          |    21 
 4          |    30
```

A vanilla `group by` statement groups by exact `value`:

```
select count(sale_number), value from table group by value
```

Would give:

```
count(sale_number) | value 
       ------------+-------
        1          |    10
        1          |    11
        1          |    21 
        1          |    30
```

Is it possible to group by inexact numbers with a threshold (say +/- 10%)? Giving the desired result:

```
count(sale_number) | value 
       ------------+-------
        2          |    10
        2          |    11
        1          |    21 
        1          |    30
```

Comment: What would you do if the values were 10, 11, 12, 13,  14?

Comment: @GordonLinoff excellent point. I would group each of the five values together if 10, 11, 12, 13, 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.value >= t.value * 0.9 and
              t2.value <= t.value * 1.1
       ) as cnt
from t;
```